# Roots of polynomial $a z \overline{z} + \overline{b}z + b \overline{z}+c$: is my solution correct

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Let $a,c \in \mathbb R$ and $b \in \mathbb C$ with $|b|^2 - ac > 0$.

To solve this I  distinguished 4 cases. Now I am interested in the case

> $a =0, c\neq 0$

-

> Please can you tell me if my solution is correct?

We have $b\neq 0$ and the equation reduces to

$$b \overline{z} + \overline{b} z + c= 0$$

For any two real vectors $a,b$ we have $a\cdot b = \|a\| \|b\| \cos \theta$. For any two complex numbers $b,z$ the real dot product can be defined as $b \cdot z := \operatorname{Re}{(b \overline{z})}$.

To find theta, we make $z$ and $b$ unit length to obtain

$$ b \cdot z = - c |b| |z|$$

hence $\cos \theta = - c$ and hence $\theta = \arccos -c$. Since $b \overline{z} + \overline{b} z = b \cdot z $ we have

$$ \|z\| \|b\| \cos \theta  = -c$$

and hence

$$ \|z\|   = {-c \over \|b\| \cos \theta}$$

This only has a solution when the right hand sidde is non-negative.

> Is there anything else I could say about the right hand side?

Comment: "$b \overline{z} + \overline{b} z = b \cdot z$" How do you define dot product of complex numbers? For example, $b=-1$, $z=1$ would give LHS $=-2$.

Comment: I edited to include the definition!

Comment: this is polynomial in what variable?

Comment: $z$ and $\overline{z}$...

Comment: I think it's misleading to call it a polynomial. There's only one independent variable, and it's not a polynomial in that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've made few a minor errors, and have taken an unhelpful direction by considering polar coordinates.

The first error is that $b\overline{z} + \overline{b}z$ is $2b\cdot z$ rather than $b\cdot z$. Secondly, you've computed $\theta$ by assuming $b$ and $z$ are unit length, whereas really $\theta$ depends on the sizes of these numbers. Perhaps you're thinking that $r, \theta$ are unique rather than a locus of solutions.

Instead of using polar coordinates, you can simply note that the vector equation for a line is $\vec{v}\cdot \vec{n} = \lambda$ where $\vec{n}$ is the unit normal to the line, and $\lambda$ the distance of the line from the origin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please could you elaborate on why the angle between two vectors depends on their length?

Comment: Also, in your last sentence, did you mean to write "distance of the point on the line from the origin"?

Comment: It's not clear to me that there is more than one or two solution(s): we have $\lambda = -{c \over 2}$ and $\vec n = b / |b|$. How can there be more than one $v$ satisfying the equation $\vec v \cdot \vec n = \lambda$?